# Vertically Align Center Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to align a bunch of logos that are different heights vertically center. They are inside a list which is also centered horizontally.

https://jsfiddle.net/mtcruere/8/

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
li > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 105px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/142x39"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/181x87"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/157x45"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/161x35"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/186x85"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/140x52"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` for `li` this will make the `div` to middle

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li > div {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 105px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/142x39"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/181x87"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/157x45"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/161x35"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/186x85"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/140x52"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**More Option:-**

Add `vertical-align: top;`(which also works) for `li` this will make the `div` to take care of the vertical alignment

**Explanation:-**

> you have given `display: flex;` in div itself(thats why `vertical-align: top;` works). it takes care of the
>   vertical align middle. so you dont need to align it manually in
>   `li`.by default `li` takes `vertical-align:baseline`. so to prevent it
>   we have to change it to top(either middle)

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

li > div {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 105px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/142x39"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/181x87"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/157x45"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/161x35"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/186x85"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/140x52"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont know how vertical-align: top will make the images to be placed in middle..!!!?? How it worked? only vertical align middle will make the element to be sit on middle vertically. can u plz explain? :)

Comment: I have added explaination :)

Comment: So why you have added vertical align top?

Comment: by default it will take vertical-align:middle. so to prevent it we have to change it to top

Comment: vertical-align:middle is what we needed. why to again add top to prevent that middle?

Comment: I have explained more now :)

Comment: that is what i am saying, the questioner needs verical align middle. as u said li has default vertical align middle, y to prevent that middle and add top?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `vertical-align: middle;` for the `li` element too.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0bbboj29/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You just need add these three css properties to ul...{align-items: center; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap;}

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
li > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 105px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/142x39"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/181x87"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/157x45"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/161x35"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/186x85"></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="http://placehold.it/140x52"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: guess you could add some explanation to the solution, otherwise it would not be acknowledged...

Comment: You just need add these three css properties to ul...{align-items: center; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap;}

Comment: Of course, but you should mention that in your answer so that anyone reading that would find it easy to understand what you did...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
li {
    display: inline-block; <<
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

with

```
li {
    display: block; <<
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a simpler html structure as compared to above. Consider the following markup:

```
<ul class="container">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/161x35"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></li>
  ....
  ....
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></li>
</ul>
```

And use following styles with some other adjustments:

```
ul {
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
li {
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 105px;
}
```

```css
ul.container {
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  height: 105px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/142x39"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/181x87"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/157x45"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/161x35"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/186x85"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/140x52"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

only thing you will need is in code Snippest

```css
li{
  width : 200px;
  display : inline-block;
  vertical-align : middle;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<ul style="" align="center">
   <li class="class-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/142x39"></img></div>
   <li class="class-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/181x87"></img></div>
   <li class="class-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/157x45"></img></div>
   <li class="class-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/161x35"></img></div>
   <li class="class-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/162x75"></img></div>
   <li class="class-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/186x85"></img></div>
   <li class="class-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x42"></img></div>
  </ul>
```